# Don't see parameters option in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to declare few parameters in Jenkins(2.192) for my project but I don't see the option. Here is the screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image]

The [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Build) doesn't say how to navigate to this view. Can someone help me?

**EDIT 1**:

This is what I see in *Build Configuration* section:

[image]

**EDIT 2**:

This is what I see in General section:

[image]

**EDIT 3:**

I don't see parameterized plugin installed on our Jenkins but I noticed these lines in Jenkinsfile in other repositories. Not sure how this is possible if plugin is not installed.

```
if (params.DEPLOY_TO != null){
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the general tab, search the checkbox called "This build is parameterized". Once you click it, you will be able to add all the parameters you need.

I leave you the link to the parametrized build plugin in case you need more information:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=34930782#content/view/34930782

EDIT: I am adding the picture on the option taken from the wiki
[image: option to select]

Comment: I don't see that option. my build configuration is set to Jenkinsfile. Updated question with the screenshot.

Comment: It is near the project name and description (at the top)... You sent the build configuration that it is located at the bottom of the config page.if you don't see it check on the plugins page to see if you got it installed

Comment: I added General section screenshot to my question.

Comment: Can you check your plugins page? Administration > Plugin Manager > Installed plugins and there search for Parametrized builds ... if not installed go to All Plugins, search there and install it.

Comment: I don't see parameterized builds plugin installed but I see other repositories using this in their Jenkinsfile `if (params.DEPLOY_TO != null){`.  Do you know how this is possible if parameters plugin is not installed?

Comment: Without knowing your platform and Jenkinsfile I can think of two possibilities: that param is created by another plugin (bitbucket / gitlab), or you are using Environment Injector to pass those variables into a map called params. The question here is: when you build you got an option called: "Build with parameters"... Other option I can think (never done it, to be honest, so is a guess) is that you are calling this pipeline from a other job

Comment: Thank you so much for your time looking into this. I will check with my devops admin on tuesday and update here. Thanks.

Comment: Hope that you find your solution very soon

Comment: My Devops person confirmed that we have to define params inside Jenkinsfile or install parameters plugin like you mentioned. Accepting your answer and thanks again for your time.